# How to get/set custom Azure Active Directory B2C user attributes in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I have added a custom `Organization` field as a User Attribute in my Azure Active Directory B2C tenant, like so:

[image]

I am using the [Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) to manage users in Azure Active Directory B2C and would like to use something similar to the following code to set the user's custom `Organization` field and the user's built-in `Email Addresses` field.

```
await graphClient.Users[user.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(new User()
{
    Email Addresses = new StringCollection("myemail@mydomain.com")
    Organization = "Microsoft"
});
```

Two questions:

1. How do I set a Built-in field, like the `Email Addresses`?
2. How do I set a Custom field, like `Organization`?

This documentation shows [how to create a custom attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-custom-attr#create-a-custom-attribute) but does not tell how to access or use that attribute using the Graph Client.

This documentation shows how to [create custom attributes and edit the Relying Party (RP) file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-create-custom-attributes-profile-edit-custom).

Is there an easier way? And what is the `graphClient` code to then get/set these custom user attributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bit confusing about whether the Microsoft Graph API, and hence the Microsoft Graph Client, supports the extension properties that are registered with an Azure AD B2C tenant.

When I query a user object using the Azure AD Graph API, then the custom attributes (e.g. "CreatedTime") are returned.

`https://graph.windows.net/{tenant}/users/{objectId}`

returns:

```
{
    "odata.metadata": "https://graph.windows.net/{tenant}/$metadata#directoryObjects/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User/@Element",
    "odata.type": "Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User",
    "objectType": "User",
    ...
    "extension_917ef9adff534c858b0a683b6e6ec0f3_CreatedTime": 1518602039
}
```

When I query the same object using the Microsoft Graph API, then the custom attributes aren't returned.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/extensions`

returns:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('{id}')/extensions",
    "value": []
}
```

Unless you receive a better answer, then I suggest you use the Azure AD Graph API, and optionally [the Azure AD Graph Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient/), to get and set the extension properties for the Azure AD B2C users.

Examples of getting and setting the extension properties for users can be found at [Announcing Azure AD Graph API Client Library 2.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2014/12/11/announcing-azure-ad-graph-api-client-library-2-0/)

Comment: Thank you for your help @chris-padgett. It sounds like the Azure AD Graph Client doesn't support the get/set of extensions. Do you know if Microsoft is working on releasing this functionality soon?

Comment: Also, if I am to switch over my application from using the Microsoft Graph Client to the Azure AD Graph API, I now also need to figure out a way to safely store the currently signed-in user's `AccessToken` so that the `AccessToken` can be put into the header of every API request. When using the Microsoft Graph Client, I would just pass in the `AccessToken` as soon as the user signed in, and wouldn't have to do anything else, but it sounds like this approach won't work anymore. What are the best practices in storing the `AccessToken` when using the Azure AD Graph API?

Comment: Hi @Emilia. To be clear, both the Azure AD and Microsoft Graph APIs and client libraries support extensions, however it doesn't appear that the Microsoft Graph API supports them for an Azure AD B2C directory. I don't know if this is being considered by the Microsoft Graph team or not. If you are developing a server-based app, then you can access the Azure AD Graph API using an app-based access token rather than a user-based one, as described at [Use the Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet).

Comment: I understand now. Thank you. It seems that this feature to get/set extension properties using Microsoft Graph is coming soon, per #12 at the very bottom of the page. https://dev.office.com/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph. I'll try to update this answer when this new functionality is released.

Answer (score 3):

You are able to do this with the Micorsoft Graph API SDK.

See this example, `UserService.CreateUserWithCustomAttribute()` https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-2-B2C

To update a custom property:

```
var updateUser = new User();
updateUser.AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
updateUser.AdditionalData["extension_{app id}_{property name}"] = "new value";

var result = await graphClient.Users["{id}"].Request().UpdateAsync(updateUser);
```

The {app id} in the code above is the id of the app created by default with the name `b2c-extensions-app. Do not modify. Used by AADB2C for storing user data.` However the "-" are all removed.

Comment: Thanks for your response! This approach is clean and straight. However, it causes me the following error: "Error! Updating User information failed with message Code: BadRequest\r\nMessage: The request is currently not supported on the targeted entity set\r\nInner error:\r\n\tAdditionalData

Better detailed here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70716662/update-azure-b2c-custom-attributes-using-graph-api-sdk-error-the-request-is-cu

Any ideas on what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Aaron Hoffman's answer on how to set a custom attribute I use the following snippet to get my attribute:

```
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider)
{
    BaseUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta"
};
var user = await graphClient
    .Users["{id}"]
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
var field = user.AdditionalData["extension_{app id}_{property name}"];
```

Answer (score 1):

So first step is to find in your custom policy:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-Common">...<Item Key="ClientId">57ff56e7-40a0-43fd-a9a3-8d6c1544bcf4a</Item>
```

Custom attributes are named extension_attributename.
To get it trough graphql you will require it like this extension_{client id of the app NO DASHES responasble for storing extensions }_{attributename}
e.g. extension_57ff56e740a043fda9a38d6c1544bcf4a_mycoolattribute as you can see this is done also in the code:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-dotnetcore-b2c-account-management/blob/master/src/Helpers/B2cCustomAttributeHelper.cs#L7-L20
example for graph call: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/3545c38b-3f6b-4a4b-8820-e7f954a86e1e?$select=extension_57ff56e740a043fda9a38d6c1544bcf4a_mycoolattribute
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-objectid}?$select=extension_57ff56e740a043fda9a38d6c1544bcf4a_mycoolattribute,extension_57ff56e740a043fda9a38d6c1544bcf4a_myotherattribute,etc](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Buser-objectid%7D?$select=extension_57ff56e740a043fda9a38d6c1544bcf4a_mycoolattribute,extension_57ff56e740a043fda9a38d6c1544bcf4a_myotherattribute,etc)