# Update Azure B2C custom attributes using Graph API SDK Error: "The request is currently not supported on the targeted entity set AdditionalData:\r\n

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

As of now, it seems there is no standard way of achieving it.

After researching for quite some time I came up with the following piece of code that, unfortunatelly returns me an obscure error:

```cs
var user = await _graphApiService.GetUserAsync(userId); ; // gets existent user
var tempUser = new User
{
    Extensions = new UserExtensionsCollectionPage
    {
        AdditionalData =  new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            { residentialPostcode, userToUpdate.extensionAttributes.extension_9614eff520454054b6d79fbe0c7a5491_residentialPostcode },
            { address, userToUpdate.extensionAttributes.extension_9614eff520454054b6d79fbe0c7a5491_address },
            { city, userToUpdate.extensionAttributes.extension_9614eff520454054b6d79fbe0c7a5491_city },
            { telephone, userToUpdate.extensionAttributes.extension_9614eff520454054b6d79fbe0c7a5491_Telephone },
            { termsOfUseConsentVersion, userToUpdate.extensionAttributes.extension_9614eff520454054b6d79fbe0c7a5491_termsOfUseConsentVersion },
            { dateOfBirth, userToUpdate.extensionAttributes.extension_9614eff520454054b6d79fbe0c7a5491_dateOfBirth },
            { termsOfUseConsentDateTime, userToUpdate.extensionAttributes.extension_9614eff520454054b6d79fbe0c7a5491_termsOfUseConsentDateTime },
            { haspassword, userToUpdate.extensionAttributes.extension_9614eff520454054b6d79fbe0c7a5491_haspassword }
        }
    }
};

user.Extensions = tempUser.Extensions;
await _graphServiceClient.Users[$"{userId}"]
                    .Request()
                    .UpdateAsync(userToUpdate);
```

Finally the error:

```json
 "Error! Updating User information failed with message Code: BadRequest\r\nMessage: The request is currently not supported on the targeted entity set\r\nInner error:\r\n\tAdditionalData:\r\n\tdate: 2022-01-14T21:23:33\r\n\trequest-id: d6c9c8b9-47fc-4aa0-bb9b-328a5b260753\r\n\tclient-request-id: d6c9c8b9-47fc-4aa0-bb9b-328a5b260753\r\nClientRequestId: d6c9c8b9-47fc-4aa0-bb9b-328a5b260753\r\n"
```

--

Additional information:

My Graph API app has the following delegated permissions:

```
Directory.AccessAsUser.All
Directory.ReadWrite.All
User.Read
User.ReadWrite.All
```

Graph SDK version

```xml
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="4.14.0" />
```

Comment: If you have the requestid, timestamp please do share

Comment: Just added it to the error response body. Btw, is it possible to debug the requestId in order to find the error cause? if so, how exactly? tks.

Comment: @Dev FYI I added the required *Application* permissions in order to update a User, in opposition to the delegated ones, as it better suits my scenario. However, the issue persists. Any clues on what might be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked the error out. It seems that the proper way to update b2c User object custom fields is by assigning the new value to `User.AdditionalData` directly and not to`User.Extensions.AdditionalData`

FWIW, the code:

```cs
var additionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>();

additionalData[residentialPostcode] = userToUpdate.extensionAttributes.extension_9614eff520454054b6d79fbe0c7a5491_residentialPostcode; 
additionalData[address] = userToUpdate.extensionAttributes.extension_9614eff520454054b6d79fbe0c7a5491_address; 
additionalData[city] = userToUpdate.extensionAttributes.extension_9614eff520454054b6d79fbe0c7a5491_city; 
additionalData[telephone] = userToUpdate.extensionAttributes.extension_9614eff520454054b6d79fbe0c7a5491_Telephone; 
additionalData[termsOfUseConsentVersion] = userToUpdate.extensionAttributes.extension_9614eff520454054b6d79fbe0c7a5491_termsOfUseConsentVersion; 
additionalData[termsOfUseConsentDateTime] = userToUpdate.extensionAttributes.extension_9614eff520454054b6d79fbe0c7a5491_termsOfUseConsentDateTime; 
additionalData[haspassword] = userToUpdate.extensionAttributes.extension_9614eff520454054b6d79fbe0c7a5491_haspassword; 
additionalData[dateOfBirth] = userToUpdate.extensionAttributes.extension_9614eff520454054b6d79fbe0c7a5491_dateOfBirth; 

var tempUser = new User
{
        AdditionalData =  additionalData
};

await _graphApiService.EditUserAsync(userId, tempUser);
```